# App to External SD on Samsung I9003

Tags: app2sd, samsung-galaxy-sl

How can i install apps on Samsung Galaxy SL's external SD card?
2 GB Internal memory
2 GB Internal SD card
16 GB External SD card

Samsung Galaxy SL=I9003

Comment: You'll need to root and use something like [link2sd](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link2sd). I'm unsure of the details though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [App2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd) for this. Keep in mind that not all apps can be moved to the SD card this way, also part of them will always remain in the internal storage. This does not require rooting.

You don't actually need the app but you can also do this via the application section of the settings menu. App2SD offers a nicer interface and hides those applications you cannot move to the card, though.

One alternative is [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD). This application is able to move all apps completely to the card. The downside is that it is more difficult to set up as it requires root and a separate partition on the SD card.

Comment: Upvoted but Link2SD doesn't move the data part of the app :D.