# How to install app on external SD card on Galaxy Note 3?

Tags: external-sd, installation, app2sd, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have Galaxy Note 3 on Android 4.4 and it has a phone storage and internal storage. The apps are installed in these 2, but both are full. I bought a micro SD card but I can't install apps and games into the External Storage (external SD card). How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I've just added the `app2sd` tag to your question. You might wish to see [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) for this topic. For the specific task, I'm afraid that's not possible on a non-rooted device. See [these questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[app2sd]+external+answers%3A1) which are dealing with the issue (and having answers), e.g. [App to External SD on Samsung I9003](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23014/16575)

Comment: @Mohsen Android always uses the *primary* SD card for this. As soon as a device has more than one SD card, that usually means the internal SD. No way to change that without root. OP explicitlely asked for *external* card as he's no space left on the internal – so that's a little different an issue then simple App2SD support.

Comment: my phone is rooted . @Izzy i know that but its not move the app to External SD that option move the app from phone storage to internal storage not external storage

Comment: @Arshia that's exactly what I wrote to Mohsen above: with native App2SD, Android always uses the "primary SD card" (the internal, if there is any) only. As your device is rooted: Again my suggestion to check the [tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) and watch out for [Link2SD](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info) – which is a root-app to achieve exactly that. // Btw: please use ENGLISH here – no idea what your previous comment is about.

Comment: @Arshia sry, this community using english language ;) anyway i think : internal sd = phone storage.your question has a problem, as `Izzy` said, i think you may try this : `http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23014/app-to-external-sd-on-samsung-i9003` APP2sd - Izzy ; no problem dude ;) i have problem with this English, i try to fix it :-)

Comment: I installed the link2Sd Plus and create a partition (with instruction but i cant move the apps to that partition , i just can move the apps from phone storage to internal storage !!!